# What is the correct way of retrieving values from settings.xml file in service fabric?

Tags: .net-core, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I have a.net core service fabric microservice app.  In the startup I'm trying to retrieve values in my settings.xml file.  See example below.  I'm trying to figure out if there is a preferred or even correct way of doing this?

```
FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext()?.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config")?.Settings
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all of the configuration packages that were deployed with your service as long as your code has access to the 'ServiceContext.'  For example:

```cs
serviceContext.CodePackageActivationContext.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config")
```

`"Config"` is the configuration package's name. You may then access all of the sections, as well as the keys and values within each section from there. Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.configurationpackage?view=azure-dotnet)   on how to access this data and listen to events that occur when the configuration package changes.